# Is there a way to pass gte, lte etc in the URL query string?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, req.query

Using Node/Express/Mongoose, is there a way to pass queries like $gte, $lte in the url parameter?

I am working on a dashboard tool that has to have about 40 different query options (up to 6 of them are selectable at a time) that can be combined in any combination and am trying to find a way to pass those options in the URL instead of the controller. There are so many query options, that using the standard like `age: { $gt: 17, $lt: 66 }` in the controller is unrealistic. If I could pass something like `?age={$gte: 18, $lte: 24}` and return that range, I could then return the data correctly. Part of the problem with using the controller is that there is not a standard object structure.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the express [req.query](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) property. Then you can pass the query param like this: `<host>/api/endpoint?gt=17&lt=66`

Comment: I am using req.query, but in the example above I need to be able to get a range on age. Your example is not get the range on age, rather just two queries. I do appreciate your response. Hopefully I have clarified a bit better.

Comment: Just create out of the 2 vars the range, `let age = {$gt: req.query.gt, $lt: req.query.lt}`. I dont understand your problem.

Comment: I appreciate your clarification, I guess that there are 50 query options that cover about 1,000 fields has my brain hurting.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not a good idea to pass the filters in query string (url). This kind of data should be passed in request body with POST request. That way you can pass the complete object as you require and that too with the desired characters, some of which might cause issue when passed in url query string. Sample request in request body can be like-

```
{
    "age": {
        "$gt": 17,
        "$lt": 66
    }
}
```

But still if you want to pass the data in url then you can do the following -

Encode URL using js function encodeURIComponent(uri) where you can pass the complete uri. This will encode the special characters. Example -

```
let uri = "age={$gte: 18, $lte: 24}";
let encoded = encodeURIComponent(uri);
```

Here encoded will return something like - `age%3D%7B%24gte%3A%2018%2C%20%24lte%3A%2024%7D` which you can then pass in url after `?` and then decode on server side code to fetch the parameters.